# anonymous struct in class with linkage external

Tags: c++

If you have a anonymous struct in a class with external linkage(under public access). Will that struct be a different entity in each file?

same goes for const data members?

```
class k{
   public: 
   struct {int u;} o;
}a;
```

Comment: Um... wow.  Post code, please.

Comment: OK, now I gotta look in the Standard...  Which I don't have on this laptop, so I hope you get an answer.

Comment: I do wonder, however -- why do you care?

Comment: don't u have to know that when you redeclare in another file?

Comment: im only 2 months in c++ trying to learn as much as i can

Comment: Ah I think I misunderstood the question. The answer is yes,  each k will have its own o.

Comment: same with const members? because unless explicitly declared extern they have file scope?

Comment: @user2892942: I think you're confused about scope and linkage, here. Each `k` will have it's own `o`, and have it's own `const` members, precisely because they are members. Each instance of a class gets its own copy of member data.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I get your question (also I strongly discourage you to use something like that in your class)

Anyway each instance of class k will get their own copy of your struct o.

Also, your struct is not *anonymous*, but it's *unnamed* <sup>@DyP</sup>. You usually want to use anonymous struct/union when they are nested (and more specifically you are supposed to use anonymous union).

Example<sup>[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C1X)</sup>:

```
struct T { 
   int tag; 
   union { float x; int n; }; 
};
```

Comment: [class]/1 "A *class-specifier* whose *class-head* omits the *class-head-name* defines an unnamed class." That is, yes, it's not an *anonymous* struct, but an *unnamed* struct. The name of the struct is not `o`, that's the name of the member/object whose type is the unnamed struct.

Comment: The struct in the op is unnamed.